Why does it give error 400 when sending a request to LibreTranslate?
I'm trying to use LibreTranslate to translate the text that the user enters, it should go directly to English, all this I'm doing is with a web app.
What I'm trying to do is that when I press the button to translate it detects the language in which the user writes, once this is done it should send the translated text below the button, but it gives me an error and I haven't found a solution within the API documentation
I leave below the method that I created to make this work
Future<void> _translateText() async {  String inputText =
_textController.text.trim(); // Elimina espacios innecesarios.
    if (inputText.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _translatedText = "Error: No text provided for translation.";
      });
      return;
    }

    final url = Uri.parse("https://libretranslate.com/translate");

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode({
          "q": inputText, // Texto a traducir.
          "source": "auto", // Detecta automáticamente el idioma de origen.
          "target": "en", // Traduce al inglés.
          "format": "text", // Tipo de texto (texto plano).
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = json.decode(response.body);

        if (data.containsKey("translatedText")) {
          setState(() {
            _translatedText = data["translatedText"];
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            _translatedText =
            "Error: Unexpected response format: ${response.body}";
          });
        }
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _translatedText =
          "Error: Server responded with status code ${response.statusCode}. ${response.reasonPhrase}";
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _translatedText =
        "Error: Failed to connect to the server. Details: $e";
      });
    }   }


The error you're encountering occurs because LibreTranslate now requires an API key to use its translation services. When you send a request without including an API key, the server responds with an error, typically with a status code of 400 Bad Request.
Here's how you can diagnose and fix the issue:

Inspect the Response Body for Error Details

The response.reasonPhrase often provides a generic message and may not contain detailed error information. Instead, you should inspect the response.body, which usually contains a more informative error message.
Modify your error handling code to print the response.body:
_translatedText = "Error: Server responded with status code ${response.statusCode}. ${response.body}";

Error: Server responded with status code 400. {"error":"Visit https://portal.libretranslate.com to get an API key"}

This message indicates that you need to obtain an API key to use the API.

Obtain an API Key from LibreTranslate


Sign Up: Go to https://portal.libretranslate.com/ and sign up for a free account.
Get Your API Key: After verifying your email and logging in, you'll find your API key on the dashboard.


Include the API Key in Your Request

Update your request body to include the "api_key" parameter:
body: json.encode({
  "q": inputText,
  "source": "auto",
  "target": "en",
  "format": "text",
  "api_key": apiKey, // Add this line
}),

Complete Updated Method
Here's the revised _translateText method with the API key included:
Future<void> _translateText() async {
  String inputText = _textController.text.trim();

  if (inputText.isEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      _translatedText = "Error: No text provided for translation.";
    });
    return;
  }

  final url = Uri.parse("https://libretranslate.com/translate");
  final apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace with your actual API key.

  try {
    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: json.encode({
        "q": inputText,
        "source": "auto",
        "target": "en",
        "format": "text",
        "api_key": apiKey, // Include the API key here.
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);

      if (data.containsKey("translatedText")) {
        setState(() {
          _translatedText = data["translatedText"];
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _translatedText = "Error: Unexpected response format: ${response.body}";
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _translatedText = "Error: Server responded with status code ${response.statusCode}. ${response.body}";
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    setState(() {
      _translatedText = "Error: Failed to connect to the server. Details: $e";
    });
  }
}

Important Notes:

Secure Your API Key: Avoid hardcoding API keys in your code, especially if your code will be public (e.g., in a GitHub repository). Use environment variables or secure storage mechanisms to store sensitive information.
Error Handling: Always check both response.statusCode and response.body when handling errors. The body often contains useful information for debugging.
API Documentation: Refer to the LibreTranslate API documentation for the most up-to-date information on using their services.

Summary
The error was due to missing authentication because LibreTranslate now mandates an API key for API access. By obtaining an API key and including it in your request, you should be able to use the translation service without encountering the 400 error.
